# How correct configure socket.io in exists nextjs project with pm2

Tags: node.js, next.js, socket.io, pm2

I created a video chat for an existing next js application and it works, but it’s time to install it on an existing application, and then pm2 and my current implementation naturally failed:

```
const nextApp = next({ dev: config.dev });
nextApp.prepare()
.then(() => {
    const app: Express = express();
    const server: http.Server = http.createServer(app);
    const io: socketio.Server = new socketio.Server();
    io.attach(server);
    io.on('connection', (socket: socketio.Socket) => {
        console.log('Socket connected!!!');
        socket.on(SOCKET_ACTIONS.JOIN_ROOM, data => {
            let { room: roomID } = data;
            const { rooms: joinedRooms } = socket;
            if (Array.from(joinedRooms).includes(roomID)) {
                return console.warn('Already connected');
            }
            const clients = Array.from(io.sockets.adapter.rooms.get(roomID) || []);
            console.log('socket clients: ', clients); // can return empty array becouse another pm2 process
            clients.forEach(clientID => {
                // exists users add new user peer to self peers
                io.to(clientID).emit(SOCKET_ACTIONS.ADD_PEER, {
                    peerID: socket.id,
                    createOffer: false
                }
                // new user send offer for connection
                socket.emit(SOCKET_ACTIONS.ADD_PEER, {
                    peerID: clientID,
                    createOffer: true
                });
            }
            socket.join(roomID); // connect to room
        }
        // another socket actions
    }
    app.use.....
```

Tell me please, how to configure it correctly so that it works, taking into account that users can be on different workers?

Is it necessary to use redis in this case and will it break my code? I mean this place for example:
**const clients = Array.from(io.sockets.adapter.rooms.get(roomID) || []);**

If I must use redis then if I understand correctly I should have something like this:

```
const app: Express = express();
const server: http.Server = http.createServer(app);
const sockets = require('socket.io');
const redis = require('socket.io-redis');
const bindListeners = (io) => {
   io.on('connection', socket => {
       // previous code
   });
}
const io = sockets(server, {
    transports: ['websocket']
});
io.adapter(redis({host: 'localhost', port: 6379})); // i want to use socket.io-redis@5.2.0
bindListeners(io);
nextApp.prepare().then(() => {...next app all logic...});
```

And where should the balancer send traffic for the socket in this case? (here I don’t understand anything at all, another person is doing this, but I have to tell him this information)?
Thanks for any help.

I tried to use https://socket.io/docs/v4/pm2/

```
const nextApp = next({ dev: config.dev });
const app: Express = express();
const server: http.Server = http.createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server, {});
io.adapter(createAdapter());
setupWorker(io);
io.on('connection', socket => socketServer(socket, io));
```

// socketServer

```
export default (socket, io) => {
    console.log('Socket connected, ID: ', socket.id);
    // same code as above
```

It turns out I have 4 IO instances created for 4 pm2 processes,
and I can't get: io.sockets.adapter.rooms.get(roomID), I also think it won't work: socket.broadcast.emit

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Redis

Make sure you have Redis installed on your server. You can follow the instructions on the official Redis website for installation.

2. Update your Socket.IO configuration

```js
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const next = require('next');

const socketio = require('socket.io');
const redisAdapter = require('socket.io-redis');
    
const nextApp = next({ dev: config.dev });
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketio(server);
    
// Use Redis as the adapter
io.adapter(redisAdapter({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379 }));
    
// Your socket.io logic here
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  // Previous code
});
    
nextApp.prepare().then(() => {
  // Your Next.js logic here
  app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    // Handle your routes
  });
    
  server.listen(3000, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('> Ready on http://localhost:3000');
  });
});
```

3. Running with PM2

When using PM2, you need to make sure that each instance of your application is using the same Redis adapter. You don't need to manually set up workers; PM2 handles that for you.

Start your application with PM2

```bash
pm2 start your-app.js -i 4 # Replace 4 with the number of instances you want
```

Then load the balancer

I hope my solution would have helped you .